# A way to find intermediate fields of a Galois extension

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider a finite Galois extension $F/K$, where $F=K(\alpha)$. Let $G=\text{Gal}(F/K)$. We are looking for intermediate fields. Let $H$ a subgroup. A nice idea is to consider the element $\beta_H=\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(\alpha)$ and the intermediate field $K(\beta_H)$. The elements here are fixed by the elements of $H$. When can we hope that this is the field corresponding to $H$? I am pretty sure that this works with cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}$ with $p$ prime, but I don't know how much can I extend the proof to reach more general cases.

I looked for similar statements in books without finding them, and this seems strange to me, since in my opinion this is a pretty useful result.

Comment: This doesn't work for all $\alpha$ such that $F=K(\alpha)$. Consider the case $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $F=K(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$, $\alpha=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ when $H$ is generated by the order two automorphism mapping both $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ to their negatives. We get $\beta_H=0$ but the fixed field of $H$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt6)$. On the other hand we have [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/812039/11619).

Comment: Even with a cyclotomic field things like the following may happen: $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/5}$, $F=K(\zeta)$. Let $\alpha=\zeta-\zeta^{-1}$ and let $\sigma\in G$ be defined by $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^{-1}$. The only intermediate field is the fixed field $M=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ of $H=\langle\sigma\rangle$. Because $\alpha$ is pure imaginary we can tell that $\alpha\notin M$. Therefore $K(\alpha)=F$. But, again, $\beta_H=\alpha+\sigma(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been discussed more extensively in another thread. Let me search more.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84017/11619) is the thread I had in mind. Doesn't really add much to the other linked thread. I seem to have answered that one, so I probably shouldn't vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, you are really kind. So the trick was to take a generator to the normal basis!

Comment: Correct, Yecabel. That is a sufficient criterion. Not sure whether it is necessary :-)